How to open selected WebSerialAPI's SerialPort from Web Worker?
I want to delegate opening serial port and reading from serial stream to web worker, due to high throughput of serial port data lagging main thread.
First, user requests particular serial port
(I have to do this on main thread, since requestPort requires user interaction):
let port = await navigator.serial.requestPort()

I cannot pass selected port to web worker directly:
serialportWorker.postMessage({
  type: "open",
  port: port
})

// This returns: DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': SerialPort object could not be cloned.

I can get list of available ports inside the worker (navigator.getPorts()), but it shows a list and I don't know which particular port has been chosen by the user.
I tried using SerialPort.getInfo() to match IDs, but for devices I'm testing with (GPS receivers), it returns empty object.
Is there any other option to do it?

Ironically, SerialPort isn't serializable so it can't be passed through postMessage.
Currently there isn't a better solution for this. There are open issues on the Web Serial API specification repo to add better identifiers so that previously-used serial ports can be more easily identified:
How much info does one need to spin a port back up? #19
Need to identify previously used port #128

From the specs it seems the order in the returned getPorts() list should be consistent between contexts, so I guess that if you can identify which port you want from the UI context, you might be able to tell the worker at which index it is in the list. (untested though)
